# impersonating C# code in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, impersonation

I need to impersonate the my code to run with a different windows user id, right now i am using some code which i got from web which is calling some native libraries.

the purpose of the code is to change the permissions on a file server user directories permissions.

I can change my folder permissions, but i have the credentials of the other user to go and change the permissions on his folder. But i am running the code on my machine by impersonating him.

But, i am getting un authorized exception.

the code i am using is:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);
```

I am not sure this is working in Windows 7 or not. Is there any one who faced any issue like this..?

Exception i am getting:

```
Messagee:"{"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."}"
stack trace:
at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.SetSecurityInfo(ResourceType type, String name, SafeHandle handle, SecurityInfos securityInformation, SecurityIdentifier owner, SecurityIdentifier group, GenericAcl sacl, GenericAcl dacl)
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(String path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
at FolderAccessManager.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

Could you please share some solutions..?

Comment: Please give full details of the exception, should be helpful

Comment: edited the case with exception message;

Comment: Doesn't `LogonUser` simply return a token which you must then use in some further way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx). There you'll see an example of how to go about.

Comment: i used the same code...looks like the user with which i am impersonating does not have enough privileges..

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a domain joined machine with ASP.NET?

I got the exact same message tring this code in a asp.net application when running with the default apppool identity. Changing the apppool user to a domain user with 'domain admin' permissions solved this problem (also Windows 7).